# XSL is running automatically and generating HTML page

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a request in this website:

http://alt1040.com/feed

Using Fiddler, I see that it does 2 redirects and send me into a page with a XML.

When I use HttpWebRequest to run a GET in this page, it returns an HTML. Seems that HttpWebRequest is combining the XSL.

Is there any way that I can disable this option?

**Fiddler result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="***/~d/styles/rss2full.xsl***"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.hipertextual.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?><rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0"><channel>  <title>Hipertextual</title>  <link>http://hipertextual.com</link>    <description>La intersección de la tecnología, la ciencia y las humanidades</description>
```

**HttpWebRequest result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Hipertextual - powered by FeedBurner</title><link href="//feedburner.google.com/fb/lib/stylesheets/undohtml.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Why I can't get the XML? Is there any way to get this XML result?

Last GET information:

```
GET http://feeds.hipertextual.com/alt1040 HTTP/1.1
Host: feeds.hipertextual.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
Cookie: __cfduid=...
If-None-Match: ...
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 16 Nov 2015 13:29:30 GMT
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not seeing it do that at all with fiddler.  It's easy to think you've identified the request in question in fiddler when in fact it was a separate request made client-side by the browser.  Can you provide more info about the HTTP request from fiddler (request headers, etc.) to prove that this is what's happening?  (`HttpWebRequest` has no sort of facility for automatically transforming xml into html via xsl)

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Actually it will be better if you run in a private window. It's really strange. Fiddler shows XML if you run once. Thank you very much @KirkWoll =)

Comment: I tried with `HttpWebRequest` and got back the XML.  Can you show us the C# code?  (sorry for posting this comment twice -- I thought on second glance the problem might have been because the URLs were different, but I get the same XML back either way.)

Comment: Actually I used just a normal GET and it worked oO ...my code is SO big and will be difficult to post it here. I will just check what I am doing to do this LOL... thank you very much @KirkWoll. I will investigate my code now =)